# Understanding cpu usage

Tags: performance, cpu, cpu-usage, task-manager, cpu-architecture

I have this simple code

```
int main()
{
    while (1){}
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code on Windows, why is my cpu usage only 25%? Yet, when I run it on Linux, my cpu usage is 100%

I have 4 cores on my Windows machine, and I have 12 cores on my Linux machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because of the tool you use.  On the `Windows task manager`, CPU usage is counted as a total of all CPU resources whereas `top` displays the CPU usage as a portion of an individual CPU core.

The internal process scheduling is quite similar, it's just shown differently.

Comment: Thanks. How does `top` decide what CPU core to look at?

Comment: It is relative to the core the task is running on.

Comment: Thanks. If I have a multi-threaded program, does it still look at one core only?

Comment: @FirstJens `top` should display each core as `CPUX`, e.g. `CPU0 states:  0.0% user, ...` and `CPU1 states:  0.0% user,...`, the number is the physical CPU core the program is running on at that time, does your `top` not display the cores?

Comment: @JuliePelletier, `the internal process scheduling is quite similar`, actually, it's extremely different between Windows and *nix systems; part of the reason why `top` and `taskmanager` do display differently :)